# Passing $location.search parameters using ng-href

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-href

Something really weird happens in my current code.

So I'm using `ng-repeat` to create several elements based on an array of objects like this:

```
<a ng-repeat="report in reports" ng-href="#/report?report={{report.id}}+file=0" ></a>
```

My rendered HTML looks as far as I can tell correctly like this:

```
<a ng-repeat="report in reports" ng-href="#/report?report=81+file=0" 
class="ng-scope" href="#/report?report=81+file=0">
```

If I now click on this link I am redirected to a url like this:

```
[root-url]/index.php#/report?report=84%20file%3D0
```

When I actually of course want to be here:

```
[root-url]/index.php#/report?report=84+file=0
```

Why is the "`+`" and the second "`=`" sign translated this way, when it is correct in the links-href-attribute? Anybody had this same problem? Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being URL encoded. It still has the same value.

Currently, you only have one parameter keyed `report` with a value of `84 file=0`. The plus sign in this case means a space.

I'm assuming you wanted to have two parameters: `report` and `file`. To split parameters in a URL you have to use the ampersand symbol (`&`) instead of the plus sign.

```
<a ng-repeat="report in reports" ng-href="#/report?report={{report.id}}&file=0" ></a>
```

Comment: Thank you, don't know why I didn't see this myself. Stupid me